# Shortcut on client to remote server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, shortcut

My setup details;

- Remote Server 2012 R2 Satndard - IP 1.2.3.4
- Client PCs Win7

I would like to create a shortcut on (multiple) client PC's that points to an .exe file on a remote server. For example Google Chrome.

This is quite new to me so if somebody could explain the process i'd be very grateful.

The client PC'c will have the full program (Chrome) installed however I would like to 'point' their desktop shortcut to the shortcut on the remover server. This is so that I can use command line switches, and set them on the remote server.

The shortcut on the server resides in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

I'm sure this is easy (not for a newbie!), how would I achieve this?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory additional explanation**. Without a comment to the contrary  *possible* reasons for a down vote can be found in the tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. That may or may not reflect the actual & private reason of whoever did cast a vote.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn for the explanation. I guess I'll never know.

Comment: An educated guess though is you're missing three steps in what is considered a [well written question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), you explain what you need but omit : -+-
What have you tried in order to make it happen? -+-
What results did you expect?
-+- What actually happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a dependency on the server. Assuming standalone program, on your server - I would create a shared folder. Create junction link from "c:\yourshare\shortcut.exe" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\myProgram\myShortcut.exe"

On client open "\\1.2.3.4\yourshare\"
Create shortcut to "\\1.2.3.4\yourshare\myshortcut.exe"

That way your not directly changing permissions on "C:\Program Files (x86)" hierarchy.